# How to add data in a specific row after searching a column for a specific keyword?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

[image]

So I'm trying to figure out how to have sheets look in the username column for a specific username and then find the sum of the numbers in the "kills" column that are in the same row as that specific username.
For Example: I want it to Look for the username "Sinz_y" and for every row that has the name Sinz_y, I was it to find the sum of the "kills" in those rows.

Comment: See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a simple [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en):

`=sumif($E$2:$E,E2,$C$2:$C)`

[image]